# Printing Strings in Java

Tags: java

I need to make the following code print the letters of the alphabet instead of `int`s. How do I do it?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;

public class Main {
    String[] letters= {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N",
            "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"};
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //create the grid
        final int rowWidth = 10;
        final int colHeight = 10;

        Random rand = new Random();

        int [][] board = new int [rowWidth][colHeight];

        //fill the grid
        for (int row = 0; row < board.length; row++) {

            for (int col = 0; col < board[row].length; col++) {

                board[row][col] = rand.nextInt(25);
            }
        }

        //display output
        for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {

            for(int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {

                System.out.print(board[i][j] + " ");
                //System.out.println();
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    } //end of main
} //end of class Main
```

Comment: It's usually a good idea to step through your code in the debugger, checking the values of the variables you are accessing. This would have solved your problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suppose:

```
System.out.print(letters[board[i][j]]);
```

As pointed out in the comments, you need to make `letters` static (and while you are doing that, why not make it private and final too).

Comment: This is the correct solution, but it's noteworthy that for it to work, you also need to either move letters inside `main()` or declare it a static

Answer (score 5):

Note that you don't need a letters array.

```
board[i][j] + 'A'
```

would have worked as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the range of the ASCII code for the letter in A -Z range, like

```
for (int i = 65 ; i <= 90; i++) {
// convert int to char and print out
    char c = (int) i;
    System.out.println("" + c);
}
```